# for loop that iterates and appends values between two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm trying to code in python a for loop that iterates and append values between two columns:

```
#The example df
#List of Tuples

Nacionalidad = [('España', 'España'),
           ('Ecuador', ''),
           ('Colombia', 'Colombia'),
           ('México', 'México'),
           ('Chile', 'España'),
           ('España', 'España'),
            ]



# Create a DataFrame object
nac_df = pd.DataFrame(Nacionalidad, columns =['Nacionalidad_left', 'Nacionalidad_right'])

esp = []
for i in nac_df[['Nacionalidad_left','Nacionalidad_right']]:
    for i in nac_df['Nacionalidad_left']:
        if i == 'España':
            esp.append('NAC')
            print(i)
        else:
            for i in nac_df['Nacionalidad_right']:
                if i == 'España':
                    esp.append('NAC')
                    print(i)
                else:        
                    esp.append('INT')
                    print(i)
                break
    break
nac_df['NAC'] = esp
```

That's are my results:

```
Nacionalidad_left   Nacionalidad_right  NAC 
0   España  España  NAC
1   Ecuador     NAC 
2   Colombia    Colombia    NAC 
3   México  México  NAC
4   Chile   España  NAC 
5   España  España  NAC
```

And the idealistic result:

```
Nacionalidad_left   Nacionalidad_right  NAC 
0   España  España  NAC
1   Ecuador     INT 
2   Colombia    Colombia    INT 
3   México  México  INT
4   Chile   España  NAC 
5   España  España  NAC
```

I think the problem is in the first loop but I'm really lost fixing it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for so many loops, check this out, I narrowed it down a bit for you. Should now give you the expected result:

```
#List of Tuples

Nacionalidad = [('España', 'España'),
           ('Ecuador', ''),
           ('Colombia', 'Colombia'),
           ('México', 'México'),
           ('Chile', 'España'),
           ('España', 'España'),
            ]



# Create a DataFrame object
nac_df = pd.DataFrame(Nacionalidad, columns =['Nacionalidad_left', 'Nacionalidad_right'])

esp = []

for i in range(len(nac_df.Nacionalidad_left)):
        if nac_df.Nacionalidad_left.loc[i] == 'España':
            esp.append('NAC')

        elif nac_df['Nacionalidad_right'][i] == 'España':
            esp.append('NAC')

        else:        
            esp.append('INT')



nac_df['NAC'] = esp
```

Output looking like:

```
    Nacionalidad_left   Nacionalidad_right  NAC
0   España  España  NAC
1   Ecuador     INT
2   Colombia    Colombia    INT
3   México  México  INT
4   Chile   España  NAC
5   España  España  NAC
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic is that we have to check weather `any` `Nacionalidad_left` or `Nacionalidad_right` is `España` this can be done with the help of vertoziation operation using `numpy-module` as follows :

```
cond_df = nac_df == 'España'
condn = np.array(cond_df['Nacionalidad_left'] | cond_df['Nacionalidad_right'])
```

And finally add new column name `NAC` by using this code :

```
nac_df['NAC'] = np.where(condn, 'NAC', 'INT')
```

#### METHOD-1

```
import pandas as pd

Nacionalidad = [('España', 'España'),
           ('Ecuador', ''),
           ('Colombia', 'Colombia'),
           ('México', 'México'),
           ('Chile', 'España'),
           ('España', 'España'),
            ]
            
nac_df = pd.DataFrame(Nacionalidad, columns =['Nacionalidad_left', 'Nacionalidad_right'])

esp = []
for i in nac_df.iterrows():
    if i[1]['Nacionalidad_right'] == 'España' or i[1]['Nacionalidad_left'] == 'España':
        esp.append('NAC')
    else:
        esp.append('INT')

nac_df['NAC'] = esp
print(nac_df)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
 Nacionalidad_left Nacionalidad_right  NAC
0            España             España  NAC
1           Ecuador                     INT
2          Colombia           Colombia  INT
3            México             México  INT
4             Chile             España  NAC
5            España             España  NAC
```

#### METHOD-2

Fully vectorize solution (without any loop)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Nacionalidad = [('España', 'España'),
           ('Ecuador', ''),
           ('Colombia', 'Colombia'),
           ('México', 'México'),
           ('Chile', 'España'),
           ('España', 'España'),
            ]
            
nac_df = pd.DataFrame(Nacionalidad, columns =['Nacionalidad_left', 'Nacionalidad_right'])
cond_df = nac_df == 'España'

condn = np.array(cond_df['Nacionalidad_left'] | cond_df['Nacionalidad_right'])
nac_df['NAC'] = np.where(condn, 'NAC', 'INT')

print(nac_df)
```

**OUPTUT :**

```
  Nacionalidad_left Nacionalidad_right  NAC
0            España             España  NAC
1           Ecuador                     INT
2          Colombia           Colombia  INT
3            México             México  INT
4             Chile             España  NAC
5            España             España  NAC
```